# Multi domain certificate

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, custom-domain

What would be the best practices to support the following case.
We have a SaaS that needs to supports custom domains under SSL for unlimited companies.
I've read that there are MD certificates that we can buy to support this case but wanted to understand if we can have an unlimited number of domains.

What type of certificates, from your experience, would be most appropriate for this scenario?

Thank you.

Comment: Consider all major web servers support SNI today, you never need a single certificate to support many domains, but each domains can have its own certificate. Then even the cheapest (no cost) certificates can satisfy your needs (but you should offer your customers paid options).

Comment: I agree but I would like to avoid that solution as our users, in that case, will need to upload their certificates and we will need to automate the process of certificate provisioning on the web server.

Comment: You don't have too many options to go, as requesting certificates on behave of your customers for their domains is never something easy. Your company needs to be a CA or has a CA as partner in order to gain all the capabilities.